# Filling a drop down list box with member properties using MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, analysis, olap

I am new to SSAS, How can i fill a drop drown list box with the member properties using MDX query? eg i want only the member properties of Fiscal Year to apper in the box. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of a drop-down box you want to fill. Are you creating a Windows or Web app, or are you using SSRS or something else?

In general though, you can use an MDX query to get the member properties of attribute MyAttribute in dimension MyDimension like this:

```
with 
member measures.MyProperty as 
   MyDimension.MyAttribute.CurrentMember.Property("Property Name")
select 
measures.MyProperty on columns, 
MyDimension.MyAttribute.MyAttribute.Members on rows 
from MyCube
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "the names of each member in Fiscal Year" not "the member properties of Fiscal Year"?

You can access cube properties and list the members of a dimension in code. But if you really want to write MDX to do this, something like this would work:

```
SELECT {[Fiscal Year].defaultMember.children} ON ROWS, {} ON COLUMNS FROM [CubeName]
```

Maybe you want a certain level within the dimension though? Use `[Fiscal Year].[Quarter].members` instead.